# Dynamically changing textbox value in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to design a textbox most likely like what Google search textbox provides where it can receive data from user and check the database and suggest few examples. How can dynamically change the textbox value as the user is typing in. 
There are Event attribute in visual studio but it works in a way of refreshing page by clicking somewhere out of textbox! so it doesn't work properly.

Comment: There are many complete examples out there; google for "autocomplete textbox"

Comment: you need to use a client script to send an ajax request containing the inserted text to the server, on the server side, retrieve the value based on request from the db, and update the textbox base on the respond of ajax, based on the technology you use (mvc, web forms,...) you may use http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ , or http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use the AutoComplete control provided by the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit. See an example here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx

Basically, setup a webservice which will be polled via Ajax. Your service will take the text provided by the user, you'll do some lookup/search in your database, then return the matches back. The Ajax JavaScript then updates the textbox accordingly.